# Where to find GitLab installation directory?

Tags: gitlab, digital-ocean

I am setting up a SSL certificate on my GitLab installation. I am trying to find the root directory to upload a file ( for ssl validation via http ) but I am not sure where is the Gitlab root Dir.

Kindly, point me to where to look or find it?

Answer (score 5):

Directory structure
Omnibus-gitlab uses four different directories.

```
/opt/gitlab holds application code for GitLab and its dependencies.

/var/opt/gitlab holds application data and configuration files that gitlab-ctl reconfigure writes to.

/etc/gitlab holds configuration files for omnibus-gitlab. These are the only files that you should ever have to edit manually.

/var/log/gitlab contains all log data generated by components of omnibus-gitlab.

Omnibus-gitlab and SELinux
```

Although omnibus-gitlab runs on systems that have SELinux enabled, it does not use SELinux confinement features:

- omnibus-gitlab creates unconfined system users;
- omnibus-gitlab services run in an unconfined context.

The correct operation of Git access via SSH depends on the labeling of /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh. If needed you can restore this labeling by running sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure.

Depending on your platform, gitlab-ctl reconfigure will install SELinux modules required to make GitLab work. These modules are listed in files/gitlab-selinux/README.md.

NSA, if you're reading this, we'd really appreciate it if you could contribute back a SELinux profile for omnibus-gitlab :) Of course, if anyone else is reading this, you're welcome to contribute the SELinux profile too.

Source

Thanks to @Drew Blessing who pointed me to read on omnibus. I end up using a different method for SSL validation so I didnt need to upload a file to the root directory of GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to place an HTML file so your SSL CA can validate your domain ownership. This will not be possible with the way Nginx is configured within the Omnibus package. All requests are routed to Unicorn (the backend server).

Can you use another method to validate your ownership, such as DNS record, whois contact email, etc?

Comment: Right, that is what I am currently doing - domain validation through DNS.

Answer (score 0):

For GitLab CE Omnibus package, it's `/home/gitlab/`

For previous stand alone version, it's `/home/git/` by default.

I don't know what kind of file you are trying to upload, but usually, people usually do not upload file to gitlab's folder.

SSL cert goes to `/etc/ssl/localcerts`

Config files are located at `/etc/gitlab` for Omnibus package

`/home/git/gitlab` for prev stand alone version